# Icecast User Auth and Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, icecast

I run an Icecast2 server where the streams are available from my website using the Web Audio API. I am wanting to set up private streams using Icecast User Basic Auth. Acessing these streams can be done using: http://Username:Password@example.com/stream.

The problem I am facing is that I want to pass the URL to WEB Audio API as http://example.com/stream and Authenticate using XMLHTTPRequest, if that's possible; however, the request is failing CORS preflight and I am not sure if I am correctly setting my headers.

As a note, I have also tried supplying the URL with the username and password without using any requests and get the message: `The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence.` So I guess I need to send a request regardless.

I am currently testing this on my local network. The Icecast server is running on linux and the webpage I am testing is running on windows using IIS. Icecast ip is `192.168.1.30:6048` and IIS is on `127.0.0.1:80`

Below is the relavent parts of my Icecast config file and the XMLHTTPRequest I am using. I also currently in my testing have global headers turned off in the Icecast config:

```html
<mount>
    <mount-name>/test-stream.ogg</mount-name>
    <authentication type="htpasswd">
        <option name="filename" value="/usr/share/icecast2/user_auth"/>
        <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
    </authentication>
    <http-headers>
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://127.0.0.1" />
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization" />
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, OPTIONS" />
    </http-headers>
</mount>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let username = "User1";
    let password = "Pass1";

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://192.168.1.30:6048/test-stream.ogg', true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin','http://127.0.0.1');
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
                
    xhr.onload = function() {
        // Do Stuff...
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of messing around with settings and even further research I found that there appears to be some unspecified issues with trying to use Icecast authentification on webservers that are on localhost.

I was able to solve the problem by moving everything to public servers and adding SSL to Icecast.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the top of your Icecast config file (this enables * CORS)

```
<icecast>
    <http-headers>
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since" />
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, OPTIONS, HEAD" />
    </http-headers>
    <limits>
...
```